# event Ext.view.ViewView after Refresh

Tags: extjs

I need an event which will be fired when items in [DataView](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.view.View) are ready as DOM elements, when [refresh()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.view.View-event-refresh) is fireing the items are still not ready

Thanks

viewready may not be used becouse it fires only onse, I need handle event after each refresh

Answer (score 0):

I think [viewready](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.view.View-event-viewready) is what you are after. If this doesn't work, [afterrender](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.view.View-event-afterrender) should.

Comment: Are you positive you don't get the DOM after refresh? The code suggests you should.

Comment: Yes I am absolutely sure, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If you need an event that fires AFTER refresh has completed then you can add one. Within the view component of your choice, or within a dataview override that would apply to all dataviews, override the refresh function, call its parent and fire a custom event when it's complete:

```
refresh : function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.fireEvent('afterrefresh')
}
```

You can listen for that event like any other e.g.

```
me.on({
        afterrefresh : me.doSomethingAfterRefresh,
        scope        : me
});
```